# fileReader is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, filereader

I have tried to read file content by using JavaScript like this

```
function readFile (evt) {
   var files = evt.target.files;
   var file = files[0];   
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(){
     alert(this.result);            
   }
   reader.readAsText(file)
}
```

It is working fine but not working in IE browser.
How to resolve this?

Comment: Simple answer: don't use the client to read files... It'll never be reliable.

Comment: @Nile: I bet it will. Give it a couple of years. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're not using IE10, you *can't* resolve this, it's just [not a feature that IE9 and earlier have](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi).

Answer (score 3):

[FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader) is supported only in IE 10+

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

You really should check for browser features before trying to use them.

The [file API is not supported on IE before version 10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi).